# Python: Find distinct abreviations of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that I want to abbreviate to the shortest distinct form.

Original strings:

```
topology
track
translate
trunk
tunnel
ucse
udp
usb
user-group
```

Abbreviated strings:

```
to
trac
tran
tru
tu
uc
ud
usb
use
```

How would I do that in python (3)?

Comment: Too broad, what have you tried? what errors did you hit? SO isn't a code writing service, sorry.

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So shortest unique prefix. That can be done with a trie simply build one and then walk down each branch and report the prefix of each branch that has a single child.

Comment: So why is topology no abbreviated to "t"?

Comment: `to` is a unique prefix. `t` is not.

Comment: The abbreviated strings form a prefix-free language.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

words = """\
topology
track
translate
trunk
tunnel
ucse
udp
usb
user-group""".splitlines()


def prefixes(word):
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        yield word[:i]


def main():
    prefix_counts = Counter()
    for word in words:
        prefix_counts.update(prefixes(word))
    for word in words:
        for prefix in prefixes(word):
            if prefix_counts[prefix] == 1:
                print(prefix)
                break
        else:
            # word is a prefix of another word
            print(word)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but here's a way to do it using list comprehension:

```
myList = [
    'topology',
    'track',
    'translate',
    'trunk',
    'tunnel',
    'ucse',
    'udp',
    'usb',
    'user-group'
]

abbrevs = [
    next(
         word[:k] for k in range(1, len(word)+1) 
         if k==len(word) or not any(other.startswith(word[:k])
                                    for other in myList if word!=other)
    )
    for word in myList
]

print(abbrevs)
#['to', 'trac', 'tran', 'tru', 'tu', 'uc', 'ud', 'usb', 'use']
```

Comment: Nice. I would simplify the code by replacing `i != j` with `word != other` and removing the extra parentheses in `next((...))`

Comment: @AlexHall that is a good point. In addition to being simpler, checking `word != other` is also more robust because it will handle the case of a repeated word in the list.